# Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Prove $(-a)u=-(au)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{F}, ~ u \in V$

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm struggling with the following question:

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and let $V$ be a vector space over
>   $\mathbb{F}$. Prove $(-a)u=-(au)$ for all $a \in \mathbb{F}, ~ u \in
>  V$

So far I have done

$(-a)u=(-a \cdot 1)u~$ (Existence of one in the field) $=-a(1 \cdot u)~$ (Commutativity of multiplication in the vector space) $=-a(u)~$ (Existence of one in the vector space.)

This looks very close to the final answer but I can't seem to move forward.

Any help?

Also I'm struggling very much with similar proofs for vector spaces/fields/rings so is there any tips you can give me at all.

Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a \in \mathbb{F}, ~ u \in V$ you have:
$$0=0u=(a+(-a))u=au+(-a)u$$ using the property $0=0u$ (that is proven using the identity $0u=(0+0)u = 0u+0u$) and the distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition. As the inverse element for addition is unique you get the desired result $$(-a)u=-(au).$$

Comment: Lovely answer, please tell me how I can get as good like you are, I seem to spend time trying to do these always get stuck and can't even remember all the axioms without constantly looking at my notes. I envy your talent.

Comment: @Mr. Sangwa Thanks. I'm afraid that talent is in fact the name for years of practice!

Comment: Hopefully I can get there one day :). One last question how do you go from $(-a)u$ to $-(au)$?

Comment: By definition $-(au)$ is the additive inverse of $au$, i.e. the **unique** element satisfying $au +-(au)=0$. As you also have $au+(-a)u=0$, you get $(-a)u=-(au)$ (by unicity).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.